# What is the 'linked to element' called?

Tags: html

This may seem like a stupid question and it maybe/probably is.
If the element where a user clicks on to get somewhere is called anchor/link, what is called the element where it is linked to.
[fiddle for demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/ykgbp4b4/)

```
<a href="#whatisthiscalled">go to what is this called</a>
<div id="whatisthiscalled">What is this element called, other then div/node/dom element.</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would call it the 'target'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "target".  In older versions of HTML there was a "name" attribute that worked only on anchor tags, but the newer syntax using ID on any element has largely supplanted it.

Comment: I believe the target attribute is still alive and well, and it has nothing to do with named/bookmark anchors. The old syntax relied on the name attribute of the element being linked to instead of the ID.

Comment: Okay, sorry for any confusion, target is still an attribute for anchor tags, but this defines if it should be opened in a new tab/window or same window.
But it could be indeed be read as follow: should the target open in a new window. Makes sense I guess now :)

Comment: Curse it, I have too many versions of HTML in my head!  The attribute I was thinking of was NAME, not TARGET.  The latter is indeed alive and well.  Answer updated, and thanks to @j08691 for the correction.